# which method is called before didSelectItemAtIndexPath in UICollectionView..?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I m using `UICollectionView` to display thumbnails of images.

I want to add an image to indicate that image is getting downloaded from net. I am adding image as subview of the view in which Collection View is added.

I am facing problem as the image gets added to view only after whole action in ***didselectItemAtIndexPath*** is performed.

But I want the images to get added as soon as user selects any cells.

I tried to add image in ***shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath*** but it is of no help. Please help me. I m tripped. Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSArray *collectionViewArray = downloadedBodyImages[[(DownloadIndexedCollectionView *)collectionView indexPath].section];
NSString *str = [collectionViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

NSArray *collectionViewArray2 = downloadedDressesImages[[(DownloadIndexedCollectionView *)collectionView indexPath].section];
NSString *str2 = [collectionViewArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:str2 ];
selectedBodyImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1]];
selectedDressImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2]];

[self drawRect:crop_rect :selectedBodyImage :selectedDressImage];
[self getCordinatesOfImage:selectedBodyImage withCordinates:[downloadedImagesCoordinates[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] inFrame:crop_rect];

}
```

shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self addHud];
return YES;
}
```

addHud method is as

```
- (void)addHud
{
    _hud = [[ProgressHud alloc]init];
    [_hud addHudToView:_downloadView animated:YES ];
     //hud.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    [_downloadView addSubview:_hud];
    [_downloadView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

if I am calling addHud method in Button action simply it works fine.

Comment: A cell is highlighted before it is selected. Look into the delegate methods that tell you about when a cell is highlighted.

Comment: I dont want to highlight cell. I want to add image as UIActivity Indicator while   images are fetched online.

Comment: why downvote after an year ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - you are using synchronous methos for loading imeges. It's really bad. Try using [SDWebImageCache](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) downloader instead.
As I understand your problem, you need to add some mark that image loaded. As soon as SDWebImageCache library loads image it puts it in cache. After image is loaded, reload collection view cell and in configuration part(whenever it in CellForRow or WillDisplay methods) check for cache. If image there - set cell's property that responsible for this "mark" to shown or hidden state

Comment: Thank u @maxim for the prompt reply.can u show me how to use SDWebImageCache downloader for the same process . Some code would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per [SDWebImageDownloader documentation](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-asynchronous-image-downloader-independently), on _didSelectItemAtIndexPath_ you start download and wait for success of failure callback. For displaying proper state you need to create model(smth like MyImageModel) with image URL and state machine that has 4 states: DownloadNotStarted, Downloading, Downloaded and DownloadingFailed. 
You array _downloadedBodyImages_ will contain those objects instead of bare URLs. As downloading started you set proper state to model and reload tableView.

Comment: Your cell should react on state and perform some UI actions. 
Adding gist as pseudocode example
https://gist.github.com/MaxRandom/ecab07664c121bcb137f

You can query image from cache by using [this code snippet](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-asynchronous-image-caching-independently)

Answer (score 1):

Using `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` is fine, you just need to process asynchronously as your current approach with `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is a synchronous request and blocks the main thread until that download is complete.

Consider using SDWebImage and the `UIImageView` extension it adds to manage the image download and display. It also supports a placeholder image that you can supply to indicate that the download is in progress.

Comment: can u show me how to do it asynchronously. Some code would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow the guide on the SDWebImage github page

Comment: Thanks a tonn for the explanation.. :)